# How can you replicate a bug seen when installing an app via App Bundle from the Google Play store?

Tags: android, android-studio

We've developed an app that works flawlessly when run from Android Studio with the following configuration:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

To simulate a Google Play store installation, we selected "Deploy: APK from app bundle".

[image]

However, the bug (which prevents restoring user preferences) doesn't manifest when we run the app from Android Studio. It only appears when we install the app on an emulator directly from the Google Play store.

Our app is deployed as an App Bundle. Do you have suggestions on setting up a test environment that more closely mirrors the conditions of a Google Play download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the following steps to reproduce a problem that occurs only with the App bundle uploaded to Google Play.

```
// Generate APKs.
bundletool build-apks --bundle=~/Desktop/com.xxx-536-5.36-release.aab --output=~/Desktop/output.apks --ks=~/xxx/my-release-key.jks --ks-key-alias=xxx

// Install APK to connected device. Connected device can be an emulator.
bundletool install-apks --apks=~/Desktop/output.apks
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have suggestions on setting up a test environment that more
> closely mirrors the conditions of a Google Play download?

Yes. I can recommend you to use Google Play [Internal Testing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/).

**How to setup**

[Doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en)

Comment: Yes. We are currently download the app into Emulator using Internal Testing channel. However, it is not practical to debug and find out the root cause, without doing it via Android Studio. Imagine we need to modify/run/observe the app for 50 times. It is not practical to do it via Internal Testing channel. The most ideal, is we are able to deliver the exact same binary as Google Play's to emulator using Android Studio.

Comment: After doing some research, I found this information. https://developer.android.com/tools/bundletool If you check it out, maybe it will help.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your suggestion, I've found a solution.

Comment: You’re welcome.